# how to display "GOOD MORNING" or "GOOD AFTERNOON" or "GOOD NIGHT" depending upon the current time using oracle

Tags: oracle10g

how to display "GOOD MORNING" or "GOOD AFTERNOON" or "GOOD NIGHT" depending upon the current time

Comment: Don't post ur homework questions here ........

Comment: BEGIN
  FOR I IN CR LOOP 
   IF TO_CHAR(I.SYSDATE,'HH24')>=0 AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')<12 THEN
    Dbms_output.put_line(' GOOD MORNING');
   ELSIF TO_CHAR(I.SYSDATE,'HH24')>=12 AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')<18 THEN
    Dbms_output.put_line('GOOD EVENING ');
   ELSE  
    Dbms_output.put_line('GOOD NI8 '); 
   END IF; 
  END LOOP;
 END;

Answer (score 2):

DECLARE 
 CURSOR CR IS SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

BEGIN

FOR I IN CR LOOP

IF TO_CHAR(I.SYSDATE,'HH24')>=0 AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')<12 THEN

```
Dbms_output.put_line(' GOOD MORNING');
```

ELSIF TO_CHAR(I.SYSDATE,'HH24')>=12 AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')<18 THEN

```
Dbms_output.put_line('GOOD EVENING ');
```

ELSE

```
Dbms_output.put_line('GOOD NI8 ');
```

END IF;

END LOOP;

END;